# Inner border-radius on a table cell

Tags: css, html-table

I'm trying to create a photo frame with a HTML table and some CSS.
I want to add an inner border-radius to it, but I can't find a way to color "edges" (spaces between "normal border" and "border with radius").

Here's a [fiddle that showcases my problem](https://jsfiddle.net/p2wktm6n/). The objective is to color the edges of the center cell, without coloring it (it must be transparent to show what's underneath, the table background color in the example).

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  background-color: aqua;
}
td {
    border: solid 1px red;
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
td.middle {
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: transparent;
}
tr:first-child td { border-top-style: solid; }
tr td:first-child { border-left-style: solid; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1.1</td>
    <td>1.2</td>
    <td>1.3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.1</td>
    <td class="middle">2.2</td>
    <td>2.3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3.1</td>
    <td>3.2</td>
    <td>3.3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `radial-gradient` for this

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  background-color: aqua;
}

td {
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

td.middle {
  background:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent 99%,red 100%);
}

tr:first-child td {
  border-top-style: solid;
}

tr td:first-child {
  border-left-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1.1</td>
    <td>1.2</td>
    <td>1.3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.1</td>
    <td class="middle">2.2</td>
    <td>2.3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3.1</td>
    <td>3.2</td>
    <td>3.3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For a custom radius you will need 4 gradient:

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  background-color: aqua;
}

td {
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

td.middle {
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left, transparent 98%,red 100%) top    right,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right,transparent 98%,red 100%) top    left,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    left, transparent 98%,red 100%) bottom right,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    right,transparent 98%,red 100%) bottom left;
  background-size:25% 25%; /* adjust this to control the radius (from 0% to 50% or pixel value)  */
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

tr:first-child td {
  border-top-style: solid;
}

tr td:first-child {
  border-left-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1.1</td>
    <td>1.2</td>
    <td>1.3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.1</td>
    <td class="middle">2.2</td>
    <td>2.3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3.1</td>
    <td>3.2</td>
    <td>3.3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks interesting!
How could this be implemented with a border-radius? The inner div would not be perfectly round 100% of the time (see https://jsfiddle.net/p2wktm6n/ for example)

Comment: This does work on HTML elements that have same width and height ; on "rectangular" elements, the radius-gradient will look stretched, compared to border-radius render

Comment: @RémyRaes use pixel value instead of percentage value. It works the same with border-radius when using % vs px

Answer (score 1):

you need to consider a new element inside your `td`
 if there gonna be an image , you won't need that `span` inside your div

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  background-color: aqua;
}
td {
    border: solid 1px red;
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

td.middle {
  padding: 0px;
}
#center_frame{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
      border: solid 1px red;
    background-color: lightblue;
    text-align: center;
}

#center_frame span {
  line-height: 100px;
}
tr:first-child td { border-top-style: solid; }
tr td:first-child { border-left-style: solid; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1.1</td>
    <td>1.2</td>
    <td>1.3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.1</td>
    <td class="middle">
      <div id="center_frame"><span>2.2</span></div>
    </td>
    <td>2.3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3.1</td>
    <td>3.2</td>
    <td>3.3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer my question, as the cell background color must be transparent to let the table color appear, and not simply copy/paste it.

Comment: @RémyRaes snippet updated , check if it's what you looking for

Comment: your first version was visually correct regarding the expected result, the only problem being that the inner div needs to be transparent to show table color.

Comment: if you want your `td` to be red , and it's child with `transparent background` , there is no way to show table background at div's child element , not with html css , when you set an item's background to transparent , it shows parent background

Comment: If you have any other idea, I'm curious to hear them :)

Comment: if you mean to display a part of an image in center , you don't need these at all , you give your circle a `background-size:contain;` and the BG image goes to it's original size , so only a part of the image is visible . if you want it to be colorful like snippet , then the snippet is the closest way