# CSS scintillation with radius-background transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, radial-gradients

I'm building a script that focuses HTML elements. One problem was to match the focused element border-radius, which I resolved using radial-gradient (see [Inner border-radius on a table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60956703/inner-border-radius-on-a-table-cell)).

However, when transitioning between two elements, a kind of white border appears on the focus element (between the "hello" element and its shadow in [my example](https://jsfiddle.net/kvcLmwrs/) [transitions are triggered automatically]).

```js
const hello = document.getElementById('hello');
var target = 'blue';
var radius = '';
var left = '';
var width = '';
var y = '';

focus();
setInterval(() => focus(), 3000);

function focus() {
 if (target === 'blue') {
   radius = '5px';
    left = '50px';
    width = '100px';
    y = '50px';
  } else {
   radius = '25px';
    left = '300px';
    width = '200px';
    y = '100px';
  }
  hello.style.top = y;
  hello.style.left = left;
  hello.style.width = width;
hello.style.background =
           `radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left, transparent 98%, #000000bb 100%) top right,
            radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right,transparent 98%, #000000bb 100%) top left,
            radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    left, transparent 98%, #000000bb 100%) bottom right,
            radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    right,transparent 98%, #000000bb 100%) bottom left`;
            hello.style.backgroundSize = `${radius} ${radius}`;
                hello.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
                
                target = (target === 'blue') ? 'red' : 'blue';
}
```

```css
#uno {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}

#dos {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  left: 300px;
  top: 100px;
}

#hello {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 60px;
  top: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2050px #000000bb;
  
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="uno"></div>
<div id="dos"></div>
<div id="hello"></div>
```

Here's the style for the "hello" focuser element:

```
/* shadow that hides rest of the page */
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2050px #000000bb;
/* having a smooth transition on width, height and background */
transition: all 2s ease;
```

The glittering effect seems **not** to appear on Firefox, so maybe it's a chromium-related issue.

In case you only have Firefox, here's a screenshot of the fiddle:
[image]

Any idea where the issue might come from?

Comment: You won’t solve that. It will probably disappear in few versions, it won’t be there for some user and you’ll see other bugs in other browsers too. Either be happy with lovely animation or use canvas to do it pixel perfect. (Also you can report it to google/chrome)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the transition of `background-size` combined with `background-position` where you are using percentage values (yes the keywords `right`,`bottom`,etc are equivalent to percentage). You may also notice that it doesn't happen for the top/left corner because the position isn't changing there.

One way to avoid this is to consider pixel value to position the background instead of percentage values.

Here is an example where I will simplify your code using CSS varible and toggling classes:

```js
const hello = document.getElementById('hello');

focus();
setInterval(() => focus(), 3000);

function focus() {
  hello.classList.toggle('red');
  hello.classList.toggle('blue');
}
```

```css
#uno {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}

#dos {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  left: 300px;
  top: 100px;
}

#hello {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2050px #000000bb;
  background:
     radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left, transparent 98%, #000000bb 100%) var(--l) 0,
     radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right,transparent 98%, #000000bb 100%) 0 0,
     radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    left, transparent 98%, #000000bb 100%) var(--l) var(--t),
     radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    right,transparent 98%, #000000bb 100%) 0 var(--t);
  background-size:var(--s) var(--s);
  border-radius:var(--s);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.blue {
  left:50px;
  top:50px;
  width: 100px;
  --s:5px;
  --t:95px; /* height - border-radius */
  --l:95px; /* width  - border-radius */
}
.red {
  left:300px;
  top:100px;
  width: 200px;
  --s:25px;
  --t:75px;  /* height - border-radius */
  --l:175px; /* width  - border-radius */
}
```

```html
<div id="uno"></div>
<div id="dos"></div>
<div id="hello" class="red"></div>
```

Comment: Looks nice !
Unfortunately, due to browser-compatibility issues, I can't use CSS vars ; and it seems that applying the whole "background" formula + backgroundSize + borderRadius via "hello.style" with correct parameters set up in javascript still produces the bug. Did I miss something?

Comment: @RémyRaes share the new code your are using so I can see

Comment: Didn't succeed in reproducing the issue in a fiddle, will post a new message if I run onto it again

Comment: Apologies, I used the wrong CSS feature...
I'm not using box-shadow within my solution, but a table, as such: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqna8k5b/